# Jest test fails because it doesn't recognise a props value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Having this React function, tried to run a test but it doesn't pass it:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector, shallowEqual } from 'react-redux';
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';
import {
  PrimaryButton,
  OutlineButton
} from 'react-komodo-design';

const Buttons = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const intl = useIntl();

  const orderType = useSelector(
    (state) => state.orderDetails.orderDetails.orderType,
    shallowEqual
  );

 ...

  return (
    <div>
      <OutlineButton>
        {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'buttons' })}
      </OutlineButton>
      {orderType.toLowerCase() !== 't9' && (
        <PrimaryButton
          onClick={clickReorder}
        </PrimaryButton>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buttons;
```

The test file is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Buttons from './Buttons';
import { WrapIntlProvider, WrapStore } from '../../testsHelper';

describe('<Buttons />', function () {
  it('should render <Buttons></Buttons>', () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <WrapStore>
        <WrapIntlProvider>
          <Buttons />
        </WrapIntlProvider>
      </WrapStore>
    );
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Error message: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

What can be done to avoid this error?

I've tried to add values inside the test function like this:

`<Buttons orderType="test" />` or `<Buttons orderType={"test'} />` or send it as a variable:

```
describe('<Buttons />', function () {
  it('should render <Buttons></Buttons>', () => {
    const xx = "test"; // <--- added here
    const { container } = render(
      <WrapStore>
        <WrapIntlProvider>
          <Buttons orderType={xx} />
        </WrapIntlProvider>
      </WrapStore>
    );
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: `orderType.toLowerCase()` is failing because `orderType` is undefined. Verify your useSelector is set up properly.

Comment: we should use useSelector in test file? or how should it be done

Comment: I'd recommend you have a read through [Writing Test - Connected Components](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components) from the Redux docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as redux from 'react-redux'

const spy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useSelector')
spy.mockReturnValue({ orderType:'test' })
```

Try to mock useSelector like this.